# Chrome extension with manifest v3 inject external code

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The code I need my extension to inject changes often so it's inpractical to bundle script with extension because it's to much burden for end user to constantly update their extension several times a day. This extension is not public and for company use only so it doesn't have to be in Chrome store.

I am getting CSP error when doing this:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: details.tabId },
    files: [ 'https://www.example.com/script.js' ]
})
```

Tried this:

```
"content_security_policy": {
   "script-src": [ "self", "https://*.example.com/*" ],
   "object-src": [ "self", "https://*.example.com/*" ]
},
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it:

```
const dynamicScript = fetch(...);
const data = {}   // to pass into dynamic script

chrome.scripting.executeScript(
   {
      target: { tabId: details.tabId },
      world: "MAIN",     // most important part
      func: data => {
         (new Function('data', dynamicScript))(data);
      },
      args: [data]  // passing app into func above
   }
);
```

world: "MAIN" bypasses CSP imposed by Chrome extension host. If page has CSP defined (most don't) then you'll also have to modify headers to exclude those. Not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the fetched script with eval in sandbox.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "sandbox.html"
    ]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const hoge = async (data) => {
  let iframe = document.getElementById("hoge");
  if (!iframe) {
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("sandbox.html");
    iframe.id = "hoge";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }

  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(data, "*");
}

const url = "https://nory-soft.web.app/test.js";
fetch(url, {
  method: "GET", mode: "cors"
})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    }
    throw new Error('Response was not ok.');
  })
  .then(data => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
        func: hoge,
        args: [data]
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

sandbox.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sandbox.js

```js
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  eval(event.data);
});
```

Comment: 1. This is not injecting code as in from a string variable.
2. eval(script) is not allowed in v3 on script not owned by extension
3. You could inject into sandbox.html because it's owned by extension
4. Doesn't address any of the requirements of the question -- injecting remote code into a page that is not owned by the extension or packaged with extension

Comment: Are you saying my extension doesn't work? I have tested it to make sure it works.

Comment: No, I am saying your code is doing stuff in a different scenario and under a different security scope then what I asked. Yes your code works but only because it's a solution to someone else's problem, maybe. See above as I answered my own question after many wasted hours.